# Content Grouping (not set) issue in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-tag-manager

I tried the content group in Google Analytics GA4 By using the **data layer**. It passes the all pages of my website in mentioned different category pages like the home page, product page, Atricle page and purchase funnel pages, etc. But the problem comes to the GA4 report for conversion and revenue showing (not set). why conversion and revenue showing (not set)[as showed in below image red highlighted lines shown the (not set) values

[image: 1].

```
Datalayer               
<script>                
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];              
window.dataLayer.push({             
"contentGroup": "Homepage" // Replace with dynamic content group name depending on visited section              
});             
</script>
```

Can anyone help me out how to deal with it? Any help will very useful to me.

> 

Thanks!!

I`your text` want to get the conversion and revenue of all pages in a content group GA4

Comment: For the conversion event, are you pushing the content group into a specific event parameter?

Comment: I have passed the data layer for all pages of my website not only specific event parameters

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is that you're using `contentGroup` instead of `content_group`.

Also note that:

- calling GA4 through UA tag will prevent the `content_group` to be sent to GA4 (even if both UA and GA4 calls are made)
- you may need to move the `content_group` to the `config` call

For instance :

**doesn't work:**

```js
gtag('set', 'content_group', 'Homepage');
gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXX');
```

**works as expected:**

```js
gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXX', {content_group: 'Homepage'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I searched the events that are related to a page with no content group assigned (not set). I found the session_start and first_visit events that meet those conditions.

I don't know the reason behind of this, it seems like both events are working regardless of the tag in GTM